# accessing a specific field in a table in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my view

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
  <% @existingusers.each do |existinguser| %>
    <ul>
      <li><%= existinguser.email %></li>
      <li><%= existinguser.trial_subscriptions %></li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<li><%= existinguser.trial_subscriptions %></li>
```

is returning this fake data in rails

```
[#<TrialSubscription id: 15, user_id: 58, created_at: "2014-03-25 01:29:57", updated_at: "2014-03-25 01:29:57", question_bank_id: 1, customer_id: nil, card_type: nil, card_last4: nil, manual_expiry_date: "2014-04-08 01:29:57", type: "TrialSubscription", last_active_check_date: nil, cached_active_value: nil, cached_coupon_string: nil, cached_period_end: nil, cached_cancelled_at_period_end: nil>]
```

I want to draw out the manual_expiry_date column.

I have tried this

```
<li><%= existinguser.trial_subscriptions[:manual_expiry_date] %></li>
```

I am getting this `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

and manual_expiry_date is a datetime field ?

I have also tried

```
<li><%= existinguser.trial_subscriptions[:manual_expiry_date].to_i %></li>
```

adding the `to_i`

the record is returning an array and that should be the way to do it?

Comment: Try either `<%= existinguser.trial_subscriptions.last %>`, or `<%= existinguser.trial_subscriptions.first %>`.  This should help you decide which `trial_subscription` you want to display.  Note that both these statements return `TrialSubscription` object given it exists on the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= existinguser.trial_subscriptions.collect {|trial_subscription| trial_subscription.manual_expiry_date } %>
```